# Destructor called for each object in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor

I have an array of objects:

```
Square sq[81];
```

I think it uses the default constructor to created each.

When I go though a for loop to initialize each, it calls the destructor for each `Square` object in the array.

```
for (int k=0; k<9; k++) {
   for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
      sq[count++] = Square(k, j);
   }
}
```

When `Square(k, j)` is called, is it deleting the object in `sq[]` and creating a new one?

Comment: It can be instructive to see when various constructors, destructors, and assignment operators happen: http://codepad.org/S1iH4cWD

Comment: @Bill: Very nice, except the dtor counts are confusing when you copy them over during `op=`. The whole point is to identify the object, not the content :) So, maybe http://codepad.org/ofmZpriv makes more sense.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks!  I was using the dtor counts to demonstrate that the object in the array had been overridden.  A more complete example could track initial value and assigned value separately.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: All right, you talked me into it. ^^  http://codepad.org/JPE8uYVO

Comment: @Bill: Now that's just confusing!

Comment: @Tomalak: Fair enough, yours is cleaner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sq[count++] = Square(k, j);
```

> When Square(k, j) is called, is it deleting the object in sq[] and creating a new one?

No.

`Square(k, j)` creates a new *temporary* object and `=` copies it into the old one. The temporary object is then destroyed as it is not longer required and goes out of scope.

---

BTW, you're not actually initialising anything in the loop (other than that temporary, I mean); you're just assigning, after-the-fact.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what its doing now.

Comment: @Benjamin: Yes, but not in the loop. I'm referring to the phrase "when I go though a for loop to initialize each".

Answer (score 3):

The elements of `sq[]` aren't getting destroyed. Rather, you call the *assignment operator* of each element to assign it the new value `Square(k, j)`, and the temporary object gets destroyed at the end of the assignment.

If you want to avoid the redundant default construction plus assignment, you could/should use a vector:

```
std::vector<Square> sq;
sq.reserve(81);
for (...) for (...) sq.push_back(Square(k,j));
```

If you further want to avoid the redundant temporary, use C++11 and say,

```
for (...) for (...) sq.emplace_back(k, j);
```

Comment: But then i am confused when my destructor is being called for each element of the array during the for loops.

Comment: @DFord: Sorry, I had it wrong originally. As Tomalak says, the *temporary* from which you assign does get destroyed; its lifetime spans only the single line on which it occurs. In C++11 you can avoid temporaries entirely.

Comment: @Kerrek: Thank you for your respones, i understand what its doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following sample program: http://codepad.org/S1iH4cWD

You can see several important steps:

- Before `main`, every object in `Square sq[81]` is default constructed.
- In your loops, a temporary is constructed, its contents are assigned to an object in `sq` - which overwrites what was there - and then the temporary is destructed.
- Finally, after `main`, every object in `Square sq[81]` is destructed, in reverse order of construction.

So you had it almost right, except objects in sq will only be deleted after `main` ends.  It is the temporary (the object on the right side of the `=`) that is destructed.

You may find this program helpful: http://codepad.org/JPE8uYVO
It tracks different values for initialization versus assignment.